# How to join three tables? Count, and Average SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables below with the following information

```
project.analytics 
        | proj_id | list_date  | state  
        |   1     |   03/05/10 |   CA   
        |   2     |   04/05/10 |   WA   
        |   3     |   03/05/10 |   WA   
        |   4     |   04/05/10 |   CA   
        |   5     |   03/05/10 |   WA   
        |   6     |   04/05/10 |   CA   

employees.analytics 
        | employee_id  | proj_id  | worked_date
        |   20         |   1      | 3/12/10    
        |   30         |   1      | 3/11/10         
        |   40         |   2      | 4/15/10     
        |   50         |   3      | 3/16/10     
        |   60         |   3      | 3/17/10     
        |   70         |   4      | 4/18/10   

email.forward 
        | email_id    | event_id  | employee_id
        |   1         |   1          | 20    
        |   2         |   2          | 80        
        |   3         |   3          | 40     
        |   4         |   4          | 50     
        |   5         |   5          | 50     
        |   6         |   6          | 60
```

How can I determine which emails (email_id) drove employees to work on projects(amount) by month and state?

```
Desired output:

   Email_id  |  Month    | state  |# of employee
        1    |   March   |   CA   |   1
        1    |   April   |   WA   |   2
        2    |   July    |   WA   |   2
        2    |   August  |   CA   |   1
```

I'm pretty stuck as I'm not sure how to maneuver the three tables together. 
Essentially I want to be able to answer

This email_id had this many employees work on this project on this month and state.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: What did you attempt and what were the errors or undesired results?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT c.email_id, month(b.worked_date), a.state, count(distinct b.employee_id)
FROM project.analytics a
JOIN employees.analytics b 
ON a.project_id = b.project_id
JOIN email.forward c 
on c.employee_id = b.employee_id
GROUP BY c.email_id, month(b.worked_date)
```

I am not sure what DBMS you use, so MONTH() may or may not exist there, but you should be able to find a similar function.